# nuxt отправка запроса после получения первой страницы

Tags: vue.js, auth, nuxt.js

Нужно обновлять токены после получения первой страницы которая была заренедрина на сервере.

Сначала приходит страница без пользователя, а на клиенте происходит запрос пользователя и его данные. Как это реализовать?

Я только начал постигать frontend подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Может делать запрос с axios после получения страницы?

Comment: Поидее это нужно выполнять в before mounted